# Gravitational force is not a conservative force

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, line-integrals

I'm trying to prove that the gravitational force $\vec{F} = -G \frac{Mm}{r^2} \hat{r}$ is a conservative force, but if I write it explicitly
$$\vec{F}=-K[1/(x^2 + y^2) \hat{x} + 1/(x^2 + y^2) \hat{y}]$$

we can see that 
$$\frac{\partial(1/(x^2 + y^2))}{\partial y} \not=\frac{\partial(1/(x^2 + y^2))}{\partial x}$$

so how can gravitational force can be a conservative force while it doesn't satisfy the necessary condition for being a conservative force ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust why ? it doesn't describe the force that I'm using

Comment: You did not take into account that $\widehat r(x\widehat x+y\widehat y)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\widehat x+\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\widehat y$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $\vec{x}$ \vec{x}

Comment: @user1952009 Your point being?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit vector $\hat r$ is
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x{\bf i}+y{\bf j})\ ,$$
so
$${\bf G}=-K\Bigl(x(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}{\bf i}+y(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}{\bf j}\Bigr)\ .$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}x(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}
  =-3xy(x^2+y^2)^{-5/2}
  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}\ .$$